# chalk_1.default.Instance is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, jest, typeorm

При запускe тестов через `jest` выходит следующая ошибка:

```
TypeError: chalk_1.default.Instance is not a constructor

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cli-highlight/src/theme.ts:4:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cli-highlight/src/index.ts:5:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/driver/sqlserver/SqlServerDriver.ts:9:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/migration/MigrationExecutor.ts:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/connection/Connection.ts:15:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/connection/ConnectionManager.ts:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.ts:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/test.spec.ts:3:1)
```

По стеку вызовов видно что, проблема в подключении orm-ки `typeorm`. Не могу понять как от этого избавиться.
Используемые версии библиотек:

```
  "jest": "^26.4.2",
  "jest-cli": "^26.4.2",
  "ts-jest": "^26.2.0",
  "typescript": "^4.0.2",
  "typeorm": "^0.2.25"
```

Comment: так всё понятно же! "Instance is not a constructor" - joke

Comment: а если серьёзно - сомневаюсь что "проблема в подключении orm-ки `typeorm`", да и stack trace странный (почему что-то импортируется из `src/index.ts`). Вон, у людей вроде работает  https://dev.to/caiulucas/tests-with-jest-and-typeorm-4j1l || https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5308#issuecomment-652887398

Comment: Видимо вы правы) Дело не в ней) У меня в конфиге jest были указаны пути в moduleDirectories, и один из них указывал в src. И видимо что-то от туда бралось. Поэтому и src/index.ts он показывает. Убрав этот путь - ошибка ушла)